# Closed Graph Theorem Application

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, closed-graph

I'm having trouble working out the proof for this problem.
Let $T:L^2(X)\to L^2(X)$ be a linear map such that there is another linear map $T^*:L^2(X)\to L^2(X)$ with $\langle Tu,v\rangle=\langle u,T^*v\rangle$ for all $u,v\in L^2(X).$

Show that $T$ and $T^*$ are bounded.

So I want to used the closed graph theorem and show that $\Gamma(T)$ and $\Gamma(T^*)$ are both closed. This would imply the desired result.

So suppose that if $(v_n)$ is a sequence in $\Gamma(T)$ which converges to a point in $v\in L^2(X)$ and $(Tv_n)$ converges to a point $w\in L^2(X)$ then I want to show $Tv=w$, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are Banach spaces and $B\colon X\times Y\to Z$ is bilinear, $B(x,\bullet)\colon Y\to Z$ is continuous for all $x\in X$ and $B(\bullet,y)\colon X\to Z$ is continuous for all $y\in Y$, then $B$ is continuous. (Hint: apply Banach-Steinhaus theorem)

Comment: Alas, I don't think I can use that theorem for my class.

Comment: Why is there $E$ and $F$?

Comment: As a remark note that $\Vert T \Vert = \Vert T^*\Vert$. You don't need to repeat the argument for the dual of $T$ even though it's pretty much the same.

Comment: Sorry, the E and F are leftover from me showing the Closed Graph Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u_n \to u$ and $Tu_n \to w$. Then for all $v\in L^2(X)$,

$$\langle w, v\rangle = \lim \langle Tu_n , v\rangle = \lim \langle u_n , T^* v\rangle = \langle u, T^* v\rangle = \langle Tu, v\rangle$$

Thus $Tu=w$ and so the graph of $T$ is closed. Similar for $T^*$.

Comment: Doh. It's so simple. I must be too tired. Thank you.